# How can manage dictionary according to array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, dictionary

I have a problem about dictionaries and arrays. Firstly I have two arrays one of them take items names and other take items prices. I take them from these arrays and make a dictionary named urunlerVeFiyatlariDict. Also I need count of each item in array. I make another dictionary according to array which take item names and I count items counts this dictionary named arrays. After that I want to show these datas in tableview but in this point I can't show them in correct order because I can't reach correct indexes because of dictionaries. Is there any way to find correct count of items ? I hope I ask clearly.

```
    print(orderItemName)
    print(orderItemPrice)

    for (index, element) in orderItemName.enumerated() {
        urunlerVeFiyatlariDict[element] = orderItemPrice[index]
    }

    print("urunler ve fiyatlari listesi: ")
    print(urunlerVeFiyatlariDict)

    for urunler in urunlerVeFiyatlariDict.keys {
        arraysForUrun.append(urunler)
    }
    for fiyatlar in urunlerVeFiyatlariDict.values {
        arraysForFiyat.append(fiyatlar)
    }


    for i in orderItemName{
        arrays[i] = (arrays[i] ?? 0) + 1
    }

    print(arrays)

    for t in arrays.values {
        countPriceArray.append(t)
    }
```

orderItemName = take items names array.

orderItemPrice = take items prices array.

urunlerVeFiyatlariDict = dictionary of item names and prices.

arrays = dictionary of item names and count of each one.

here output of urunlerVeFiyatlariDict: 
["denemedir": "4 ₺", "deneme 2 dir": "9 ₺", "deneme 3": "8 ₺"]

output of arrays dictionary : 
["deneme 3": 3, "deneme 2 dir": 2, "denemedir": 1]

Comment: Any reason why my last comment in your previous question didn't help? And isn't this a duplicate of that question?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson In last comment my index problem didn't solved. I have some changing in my code so question is not same.

Comment: Maybe delete your old question then or is it still relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are converting 2 arrays to a dictionary then back to 2 arrays then back to a dictionary.

That's not very efficient.

I recommend to use a struct with a `name` and a `price` member

```
struct Item {
    let name : String
    let price : Int
}
```

Then `zip` your arrays and `map` them to `Item` instances

```
var items = zip(orderItemName, orderItemPrice).map(Item.init)
```

To count the number of items with the same name group the array to a dictionary. The keys are the names and the values are the corresponding `Item` instances

```
let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: items, by: {$0.name})
for (name, items) in grouped {
    print(name, items.count)
}
```

Comment: I try to make this code but how can I reach inside of items with for loop or etc. ?

Comment: Just a loop `for item in items { print(item.name, item.price) }`

Comment: thank you for your patience with me one last question. How can I remove duplicates or more in for item in items loop ? I can't find solution on internet.

Comment: You should check for duplicates while populating the name and price arrays.